# May I see individual events of my web pages sent via GTM to GA4 or similar free event-collector?

Tags: events, storage, google-tag-manager, google-analytics-4

## TL;DR

- I want to collect and watch all events that my website sends to GTM.
- Not in debug/preview mode, but I mean in production.
- In GA4 I may see aggregates, but I'm not able to see how can I see all the details of each and any individual event sent in the past.

## Details

If I send an event to GTM, I can see it in the preview mode.

Say I have this javascript in the web page:

```js
// Setup GTM
// [...]
//
// Send data to GTM
const myEvent = { "event": "my-nice-event", "aaa": "bbb" };
dataLayer.push( myEvent );
```

My GTM in preview mode displays each individual event, and I can open and see the full JSON object, like this:

[image: How it is seen in GTM]

I have my GTM connected to GA4 as well as to other trackers (like Facebook Pixel)

May I see all the events sent by all the users, individually, one by one, when it's not set as "preview"? (Does not mind if inside GA4 or inside any other free tracker).

## Final note

If there's no free tool out there, I thought about linking GTM to some sort of LogStash and/or ElasticSearch or so. But I think that could be an overwhelming setup for something that maybe it's already ready out there.

## Question

- May all the events sent with `dataLayer.push( event )` be retrieved from GA4?
- If not: From where?
- If not: Can GTM connect to LogStash or any other free "event collectors"?